# Gstreamer 1.0 image/video player. Which way to implement?

Tags: c, gstreamer

I have a list of files (videos and images) I would like to show on the screen using gstreamer 1.0, means iterating over the elements (file paths) in the list and "play" them sequentially in the c application with "delays" e. I tried different examples which partly work, but I cannot get the whole picture together to implement.

So what is the conceptual solution for this? Should I use one "dynamic" pipeline or two (one for images - because I think here is `imagefreeze` before `videoconvert` necessary and one for video)? And how can I use `decodebin` to detect the format of the media automatically? decodebin works from the command line, but with errors like `no video decoder found for 'jpeg'` in c application?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make universal pipeline (or two for videos and images). i.e. you put to input any file from your list and get output video or image. This pipeline(s) should works from *gst-launch*. After that try to implement this pipeline in to C code, or write pipeline here.

My way:
Take file from list. If image -> create image decode pipeline, if video -> create video decode pipeline. Delete pipeline. Delay. Go to next file.